# Deselecting a UICollectionView Cell only works once

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a button that should deselect the selected collection view cell.  The first time I click the button everything works as expected and the cell gets deselected.  If I try selecting the same cell, or a different cell, and click the button a second(or more) time(s) the cell doesn't get deselected.

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let indexPaths = self.collection.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
    let indexPath = indexPaths[0]

    //Do some other things

    self.collection.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

I have implemented `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` and `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what about doing `indexPaths.forEach({ index in self.collection.deselectItemAtIndexPath(index, animated: true)})`?

Comment: Are you sure it's not actually removing, or could it be the management of selected cells in `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`. Can you post this code as well as `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I tried substituting in `indexPaths.forEach({ index in self.collection.deselectItemAtIndexPath(index, animated: true)})` and still got the same results.

Comment: I'll edit my original post to include the code you asked for Michael.

Comment: When I was copying/pasting the code to post here, I figured out the issue. I wasn't setting the background color initially in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath`